# Visual Studio Emulator : How to use PC's Keyboard Input ( Hardware ) Instead of Android Soft Keyboard

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

Im using the latest Android Studio and VS Emulator version, I try to press F4 to Active or Inactive computer's keyboard input, That cant helped me so far.

See this Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/test-with-the-emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for future answer, because this is Underrated Issue.

Just press ***Alt + F4*** and all will be worked.

**Note** : If you can't active or inactive the keyboard input, sometimes you need to spam it. Idk how its work, but in my issue, sometimes i try to press Win+F4, Alt+F4 (**im not trolling, Alt+F4 doesnt close your Emulator**), Fn+F4 or just F4. Just try that to Active. To **inactive** try to press Win+4, this will minimize your emulator then open it, and try, keyboard input will not worked again.